# error getting access token in twitter android app

Tags: android, twitter4j

i am using twitter4j in android application. i am using code with my consumer key and secret and when i logs in to twitter ,it successfully logs in at first try. but when i run the code again and then try,as i was previously authenticated,it logs me in but then gives 'error getting access token'. i don't understand how to deal with it.. can anybody please help.. i am using this code for login

```
    public class TwitterLoginActivity extends Activity {
        TextView tv;
        Button loginBtn;

        private TwitterApp mTwitter;
        private ConnectionDetector cd;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
     AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
        RequestToken requestToken;
        private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "*****************";
        private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "*****************************************";

        static String PREFERENCE_NAME = "twitter_oauth";
      static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
      static final String PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET = "oauth_token_secret";
      static final String PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN = "isTwitterLogedIn";


      static final String URL_TWITTER_AUTH = "auth_url";
      static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
      static final String URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";

      public void storeAccessToken(AccessToken aToken)   {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, aToken.getToken());
            editor.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, aToken.getTokenSecret());
            editor.commit();}
        private enum FROM {
            TWITTER_POST, TWITTER_LOGIN
        };

        private enum MESSAGE {
            SUCCESS, DUPLICATE, FAILED, CANCELLED
        };

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.twitter_login);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            mTwitter = new TwitterApp(this, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
            requestToken = mTwitter.getOAuthRequestToken;

            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_txt);
            loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
            loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mTwitter.setListener(mTwLoginDialogListener);
                    mTwitter.resetAccessToken();
                    if (mTwitter.hasAccessToken() == true) {
                        postAsToast(null, null);

                    }
                    else {
                        mTwitter.authorize();
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        private void postAsToast(FROM twitterPost, MESSAGE success) {
            switch (twitterPost) {
            case TWITTER_LOGIN:
                switch (success) {
                case SUCCESS:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    break;
                case FAILED:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                default:
                    break;
                }
                break;

            }
        }


        private TwDialogListener mTwLoginDialogListener = new TwDialogListener() {

            public void onError(String value) {
                postAsToast(FROM.TWITTER_LOGIN, MESSAGE.FAILED);
                Log.e("TWITTER", value);
                mTwitter.resetAccessToken();
            }

            public void onComplete(String value) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(TwitterLoginActivity.this,
                        TweetsListActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

        };
    }

i have also used AlertDialogManager.java,ConnectionDetector.java classes in right manner. please help
```

Comment: i am unable to see the edits.. @Ohlin

Comment: I added the `android` tag to your question. It was a bit unclear from the question title what the question was about.

Comment: it is about the login problem. when i give my consumer key and secret,the login is successful for the first time.. but when i run my app again ,i was already authenticated with my id and password,but instead of going to application,it shows 'login failed'.. and gives 'error getting access token' in logcat

Comment: What does your MainActivity contain at line number 123?

Comment: there is no line no 123. please directed the line u r talking about

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Refer this link:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial

If any doubt let me know.

It works fine...Just use the latest jar file that's it!!

**EDIT:**
Just add the following code in the oncreate off Activity:

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
          StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
          StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
```

Comment: it works well for me.. could u pls elaborate where u stuck with?

Comment: hi. i downloaded the source code from your suggested link and add twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar file in libs folder by replacing the existing twitter4j-core-android-2.2.jar

but it is not working and forces app to close. the error in logcat is linked here http://pastebin.com/Tm2waxFW

Comment: i am getting a problem. my code is here.. i am using login button for twitter login and after successfull login i want the second activity should open.. but after logging in,again the app starts from the login page instead of directly going to second activity. here is the code http://pastebin.com/CaVyPU0x

Comment: U r not getting this toast, Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Already Logged into twitter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: so, wanted to login once again in the twitter api,uh?

Comment: i mean the login button page is opening again and again even after the user is logged in.. i want after successful login,the TweetsListActivity.java should started,which is my second activity

Comment: give the intent in the else part!

Comment: its not working. yet it is placed in right position but the problem is in try block.. i think so.. try {
    requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
  }
 catch (TwitterException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();}

bcoz of this the activity is starting again n again. i want to send u my app's apk. can u give me ur email id?

Comment: send the project, so that, i can check out

Comment: i have sent it. please check it out

Comment: i am pasting it here TweetsListActivity http://pastebin.com/qtKsfCL5

PostCommentActivity http://pastebin.com/fSSMGKkL

TwitterLoginActivity  http://pastebin.com/CaVyPU0x

Comment: hey,u haven't called the TwitterLoginActivity activity in the class where u want the user to enter the twitter credentials into twitter api

Comment: what changes i have to made in d code? one more activity i used at first is SplashScreen http://pastebin.com/62VXJ0UC

Comment: i couldn't understand your flow. could help u only if i get the entire source code in eclipe

Comment: i was also using the same code with few changes i made according to my need.. u must see my posted question above. it uses the same code.

Comment: yeah i tried it.. but my above code causes one time login successful,but this code always shows login failes.. showing 'error getting access token' even at first try

Comment: i have just used my consumer key and consumer secret

Comment: it just gives the same error everytime.. here is the logcat http://pastebin.com/hFWbrVik

Comment: i am using other code.. that u refer in above androidhive link

Comment: i don't knw how to create.would u help me pls?

Comment: go to dev.twitter.com n do one.

Comment: by using the code in the above link i get the access token successfully but when i press back from second activity it goes back to the web view with authorize page i.e i have to go back through the web view to reach the initial activity anyway to avoid that